# How to maintain data object for multiple c++ files in visual studio project

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am working with `C++` in `Visual Studio`; in my project, there are multiple libraries and other exe files which are using a common INI file. My idea is that I want to load all the information in a object when project is launched, and that object should be common for every other library and applications.

How should I maintain such a common object?

Comment: Maybe just define your object in a separate source file, declare it in a shared header, then have all libraries and executable include that common source?